# How do I write a file to the correct directory whether the program is run from a jar or from the IDE?

Tags: java, jar, text-files, read-write

I'm having trouble writing to a text file when my program is being run two different ways. I can either get it to work correctly when running as a jar or from NetBeans, but not both.

I added my resources folder as a source package in Netbeans and this causes my program to work correctly in the IDE but not when running as a jar. If I don't have my resources folder as a source package and instead have it just in my project root folder it runs correctly from the jar but not in the IDE. I am trying to convert my program into a java web start application so I'd like it to run both ways but if it's not necessary then please let me know.

I am first figuring out if my code was run from a jar so I can separate my logic in the future. For now, it's the same logic either way. This code works in the IDE but doesn't save when ran from a jar. FILEPATH is the path to one of two high score files it would look like "data/classichighscores.txt". The 
temp file is an empty text file already created in the same directory.

```
  /**
     * saves the data to its own text file.
     */
    public void save() {
        File dataFile = null;
        File tempFile = null;

        String className = this.getClass().getName().replace('.', '/');
        String classJar = this.getClass().getResource("/" + className + ".class").toString();
        if (!classJar.startsWith("jar:")) {
            dataFile = new File(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(FILEPATH).getFile());
            tempFile = new File(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("data/myTempFile.txt").getFile());
        } else {
            dataFile = new File(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(FILEPATH).getFile());           
            tempFile = new File(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("data/myTempFile.txt").getFile());
        }
        try {
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    new FileOutputStream(tempFile), "UTF-8"));

            for (String line : FILEDATA) {
                bw.write(line);
                bw.newLine();
           }

            bw.close();
            dataFile.delete();
            tempFile.renameTo(dataFile);
            tempFile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(tempFile.toString());
            System.err.pritnln(dataFile.toString());
```

I also changed my xml file and manifest file in the past which might have something to do with my problem. I put this code in to have my jar file and resources in the same distribution folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project name="TheLostWand" default="default" basedir=".">
    <description>Builds, tests, and runs the project TheLostWand.</description>
    <import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>
    <!--adding resources to dist folder-->
    <target name="-post-jar">
        <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}/resources"/>
        <copy todir="${dist.dir}/resources">
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/resources" />
        </copy>
    </target>

</project>
```

I added the Class-Path line.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Class-Path: resources/
```

I expect my text file to be edited and saved with an added high score. It works correctly when ran from the IDE but not when ran from the jar. I can remove my resources folder from the source package and it'll work from the jar but then not from the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

For saving text files I would recommend serialization.

```java
//Credit to Jaroslaw Janas
    public void save(String filepath, Object obj) {
//        get the folder
//        if no folder create a new one
        File folder = new File("foldername");
        if (!folder.exists()){
            folder.mkdirs();
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(filepath);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(file);
            out.writeObject(obj);
            out.close();
            file.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("IOException is caught");
        }
    }

//    this method loades the saved object
//    from a location passed in as an argument
    public Object load(String filepath) {
        Object obj = null;
        try {
            // reading from the file
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(filepath);
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(file);

            // deserialization
            obj = in.readObject();

            in.close();
            file.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("IOException");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException");
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

For a universal directory, %AppData% might be a good choice.